# How to resolve the error 'cannot convert value of type java.lang.string because no compatible types exists in the union for the field' in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying move a table data from Oracle to Bigquery.

To get the data from Oracle, I am using `QueryDatabaseTable` processor. To put the data in Bigquery, I am using `PutBigQueryBatch` processor.

Before uploading to Bigquery, I was trying to add an additional field in data from Oracle. To do that, I was using `UpdateRecord` processor. I was following a guide from Cloudera community but it shows an error when executed.

The properties are as follows:

AvroSchemaRegistry service:

[image]

sch property:

```
{
 "namespace": "any.data",
 "name": "NDI_LOTIN",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
  { "name": "LINKID",  "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "TXNDATE",  "type": { "type" : "string","logicalType" : "timestamp-millis" } },
  { "name": "PROCESS",  "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "RESOURCENAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "CONTAINERNAME", "type" : ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "EMPLOYEENAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "TARGETDEVICE", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "CUSTOMER", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "FIELDNAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "FIELDVALUE", "type": ["null","string"] }
 ]
}
```

AvroReader service:

[image]

AvroRecordSetWriter service:

[image]

Schema Text:

```
{
 "namespace": "any.data",
 "name": "NDI_LOTIN",
 "type": "record",
 "fields": [
  { "name": "LINKID",  "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "TXNDATE",  "type": { "type" : "string","logicalType" : "timestamp-millis" } } ,
  { "name": "PROCESS",  "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "RESOURCENAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "CONTAINERNAME", "type" : ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "EMPLOYEENAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "TARGETDEVICE", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "CUSTOMER", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "FIELDNAME", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "FIELDVALUE", "type": ["null","string"] },
  { "name": "Log_TXNDATE",  "type": { "type" : "string","logicalType" : "date" } }
 ]
}
```

Note: Added new field 'Log_TXNDATE' in the schema

UpdateRecord processor:

[image]

/Log_TXNDATE : format(toDate( /TXNDATE, "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'"),"yyyy-MM-dd")

The processors are connected in the following order:

```
ExecuteSQL -> UpdateRecord -> PutBigQueryBatch
```

When the UpdateRecord runs, it shows the error message

```
UpdateRecord[id=@$!#$^]Failed to process standard flow file records[uuid = !#$%#!% , claim = standardcontentclaim[resourceclaim = standardresourceclaim[id=!#%!%#!%, container = default , section = 2], offset = 1485 , length = 761], offset = 0, name = !##%@!%, size = 761 ]; will route to failure: 
Cannot convert value 2013-12-10 of type class.java.lang.String because no comptaible types exist in UNION for field Log_TXNDATE
```

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: In avro the `date` type declared for your new field, but in expression you are using `format()` function that returns `string`. BTW, could you share the link to cloudera guide?

Comment: This was the guide: https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Update-the-Contents-of-FlowFile-by-using-UpdateRecord/ta-p/248267

The guide uses long. I thought mentioning logical type would return the required result, evidently it didn't. I am not familiar with Avro format.